# How to download file from gitlab synchronously using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file, download, get, synchronous

I need to download a file from a private gitlab server and I need the method to be synchronous. This was by previous async code and it works fine because I was using promises. But I'm having trouble converting it to synchronous. The other posts i've seen on SO either ended up using async code or didn't have options for headers.

```
            const https = require('https');
            const fs = require('fs');
            const gitlabUrl = 'https://gitlab.custom.private.com';
            const gitlabAcessToken = 'xmyPrivateTokenx';
            const gLfilePath = '/api/v4/projects/1234/repository/files/FolderOne%2Ftest.txt/raw?ref=main';
            const gLfileName='test.txt';
            
                
            function downloadFileFromGitlab(filePath, fileName) {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        var options = {
                            path: filePath,
                            headers: {
                                'PRIVATE-TOKEN': gitlabAccessToken
                            }
                        };
                        
                        var url = gitlabUrl
                        var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
                        
                        const request = https.get(url, options, (response) => {
                            response.pipe(file);
                            file.on('finish', () => {
                                file.close();
                                resolve();
                            });
                            file.on('error', (err) => {
                                file.close();
                                reject(err);
                            });
                        });
                
                        request.on('error', error => {
                            throw console.error(error);
                        });
                    });
                }

downloadFileFromGitlab(gLfilePath,gLfileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using curl

```
function downloadFileFromGitlab(filePath, fileName) {
    let curlCommand = "curl -s " + gitlabUrl + filePath + " -H 'PRIVATE-TOKEN:" + gitlabAccessToken +"'";
    let file = child_process.execSync(curlCommand);
    fse.writeFileSync(fileName,file);
}
```